supabase: canceling statement due to statement timeout
When I run function to get data below
const [users, diaries, comments, likes, step] =
    await Promise.all([
      await supabase.rpc("get_users"),
      await supabase.rpc("get_period_diaries", {
        mondaysecs: monday,
        sundaysecs: sunday,
      }),
      await supabase.rpc("get_period_comments_month_diary_three", {
        mondaysecs: monday,
        sundaysecs: sunday,
      }),
      await supabase.rpc("get_period_likes_month_diary_three", {
        mondaysecs: monday,
        sundaysecs: sunday,
      }),
      await supabase.rpc("get_period_steps", {
        weekdays: weekDays,
      }),
    ]);

It works fine.
But when I run as adding one more field invitations,
const [users, diaries, comments, likes, steps, invitations] =
    await Promise.all([
      await supabase.rpc("get_users"),
      await supabase.rpc("get_period_diaries", {
        mondaysecs: monday,
        sundaysecs: sunday,
      }),
      await supabase.rpc("get_period_comments_month_diary_three", {
        mondaysecs: monday,
        sundaysecs: sunday,
      }),
      await supabase.rpc("get_period_likes_month_diary_three", {
        mondaysecs: monday,
        sundaysecs: sunday,
      }),
      await supabase.rpc("get_period_steps", {
        weekdays: weekDays,
      }),
      await supabase.rpc("get_period_invitations", {
        mondaysecs: monday,
        sundaysecs: sunday,
      }),
    ]);

It throws error.
"error": { "code": "57014", "details": null, "hint": null, "message": "canceling statement due to statement timeout" },


But it comes with comments part.
comments has the most huge data among them.
So other fields returns right data but comments return 'null'.
I don't know why as having same data of comments between 1st query and 2nd query, only 2nd query returns null.
And When I check statement_timeout with query show statement_timeout it is 2min.
Should I extend it more?
